# Haskell preorder tree traversal for tree defined as "data BB a = L | K (BB a) a (BB a) deriving (Show)"

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree, tree-traversal, preorder

new to Haskell here. Trying to figure out how to make preorder traversal given various tree definitions. I`ve seen preorder for a tree defined as
`data BB a = L | K a (BB a) (BB a) deriving Show`

```
prefixCollect L = []
prefixCollect(K w l r) = w : prefixCollect l ++ prefixCollect r
```

However, I am not sure how to perform same operation if the tree is defined differently:
`data BB a = L | K (BB a) a (BB a) deriving Show` ?

Could please somebody help?

Comment: What do you think the variables K, w, l, and r represent in the definition of prefixCollect, and how do they come to have those values? If you can answer those questions, you will not be far from understanding how to adapt that definition to handle a reordered type definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is virtually no difference in how you would define the function; the difference in type definitions only changes how you would pattern-match against the argument.

```
prefixCollect L = []
-- K l w r instead of K w l r
prefixCollect (K l w r) = w : prefixCollect l ++ prefixCollect r
```

Both definitions define a tree in exactly the same way: as a node consisting of a value and two subtrees. The order in which the data constructor `K` lists those three values doesn't really matter.